# Querying data present within a Firestore Database array in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have my dataset modeled within the Firebase Firestore database as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of the Firestore Database]

I would like to retrieve and display the data based on the following criterias:

- isAdmin is equal to true
- isPerm is equal to true
- userID sorted in descending order

I'm using the following versions of Firebase and Cloud Firestore packages:

- firebase_core: ^0.5.0
- cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2

I'm new to Flutter, I'm not sure, how I can achieve this. Really appreciate, if anyone could help me with this. Thanks for your help in advance.

I was able to retrieve the data as shown below, not sure how to sort it in descending order.

```
  getUsers() async {
    // _userCollection.doc('uGGuMfGS2DezVHHFASw4').where('userData', arrayContainsAny('isAdmin', isEqualTo: true)).get();
    final _docRef = await _userCollection.doc('uGGuMfGS2DezVHHFASw4').get();
    print(_docRef.data()['userData'].length);
    for (var i = 0; i < _docRef.data()['userData'].length; i++) {
      print(_docRef.data()['userData'][i]['username']);
      print(_docRef.data()['userData'][i]['isAdmin']);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do with this data is not possible.  Firestore does not have a way to query for specific map values nested in array fields.  You will have to restructure this data to make it workable with Firestore.

One thing you can do is move all those array items into separate documents in a subcollection, then query the subcollection.

Another thing you can do is copy each nested value into an array to query with an [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) type query.

Comment: Hi @Doug Stevenson, thanks for your reply. The reason why I'm using this approach is to save on the cost. I might end up having millions of users and if I need to retrieve and display all the users who aren't admin. If there are around a 100k users and if I need to display this 100 times a day, then there would be 10 million reads each day, I'm not sure how I can optimize this.

Comment: It sounds like you might not have read my second suggestion about copying the relevant data elements to query into an array field and query it that way.